# Quarkus deploy to kubernetes of docker-desktop on mac

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus

I'm trying to deploy a simple Quarkus (2.3.1) application to my local kubernetes created by docker-desktop an it does not work and throws the following exception after jib has create the image of the app.

following configurations has been made in the application.properties:

```
quarkus.container-image.build=true
quarkus.container-image.group=
quarkus.package.type=jar

# for docker-desktop
quarkus.kubernetes-client.trust-certs=true
quarkus.kubernetes.deployment-target=kubernetes
quarkus.kubernetes.deployment=true
```

This is the exception that I'm getting

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.3.0.Final:build (default) on project kafka-consumer-producer: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.kubernetes.deployment.KubernetesDeployerPrerequisite#prepare threw an exception: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:53)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:234)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:66)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.BaseClient.<init>(BaseClient.java:51)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.BaseKubernetesClient.<init>(BaseKubernetesClient.java:154)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient.<init>(DefaultKubernetesClient.java:40)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.kubernetes.client.runtime.KubernetesClientUtils.createClient(KubernetesClientUtils.java:93)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.kubernetes.deployment.KubernetesDeploy.doCheck(KubernetesDeploy.java:67)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.kubernetes.deployment.KubernetesDeploy.checkSilently(KubernetesDeploy.java:53)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.kubernetes.deployment.KubernetesDeployerPrerequisite.prepare(KubernetesDeployerPrerequisite.java:22)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:820)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:450)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:91)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1050)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:141)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:64)
[ERROR]     at java.base/javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:275)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.SSLUtils.keyManagers(SSLUtils.java:130)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.SSLUtils.keyManagers(SSLUtils.java:122)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:129)
[ERROR]     ... 19 more
[ERROR] Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
[ERROR]     at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:859)
[ERROR]     at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:939)
[ERROR]     at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:735)
[ERROR]     at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:424)
[ERROR]     at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:456)
[ERROR]     at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2205)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.lambda$engineGetKey$0(PKCS12KeyStore.java:371)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore$RetryWithZero.run(PKCS12KeyStore.java:257)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:361)
[ERROR]     ... 27 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.kubernetes.client.deployment.KubernetesClientBuildStep#process threw an exception: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:53)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:234)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:66)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.BaseClient.<init>(BaseClient.java:51)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.BaseKubernetesClient.<init>(BaseKubernetesClient.java:154)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient.<init>(DefaultKubernetesClient.java:40)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.kubernetes.client.runtime.KubernetesClientUtils.createClient(KubernetesClientUtils.java:50)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.kubernetes.client.deployment.KubernetesClientBuildStep.process(KubernetesClientBuildStep.java:16)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:820)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:450)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:91)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1050)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:141)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:64)
[ERROR]     at java.base/javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:275)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.SSLUtils.keyManagers(SSLUtils.java:130)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.SSLUtils.keyManagers(SSLUtils.java:122)
[ERROR]     at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:129)
[ERROR]     ... 17 more
[ERROR] Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
[ERROR]     at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:859)
[ERROR]     at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:939)
[ERROR]     at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:735)
[ERROR]     at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:424)
[ERROR]     at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:456)
[ERROR]     at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2205)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.lambda$engineGetKey$0(PKCS12KeyStore.java:371)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore$RetryWithZero.run(PKCS12KeyStore.java:257)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:361)
[ERROR]     ... 25 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I've also tried with creating a cluster with kind.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the Container Image.
It seems more related to the cluster. What cluster are you trying to deploy in? It looks like there's some trouble when the Kubernetes Client tries to infer your kubectl settings.

Comment: Yes I have the same guess, it’s default K8s by docker-desktop

Comment: TIL that Docker Desktop provided a K8s cluster.
If you deploy the generated manifests with kubectl instead, do you get the same problem?

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72872000/321307

Comment: thx for sharing. Have to check on that later. Currently working on a different tech stack. already forgot about past issues 