# spark-submit error "To use support for EC Keys you must explicitly add this dependency to classpath"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, k3s, rancher-desktop

I am running a local [K3s](https://k3s.io/) Kuberentes cluster created by Rancher Desktop.

`kubectl cluster-info` returns

```bash
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://127.0.0.1:6443
# ...
```

When I submit Spark application (in Scala) by:

```bash
spark-submit \
        --master=k8s://https://127.0.0.1:6443 \
        --deploy-mode=cluster \
        --name=findretiredpeople \
                --class=com.sundogsoftware.spark.Hello \
        --conf=spark.executor.instances=2 \
        --conf=spark.kubernetes.container.image=hongbo-miao/hello:latest \
        local:///target/scala-2.12/hello_2.12-1.0.jar
```

I got error

```
23/03/20 18:14:10 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/03/20 18:14:10 INFO SparkKubernetesClientFactory: Auto-configuring K8S client using current context from users K8S config file
Exception in thread "main" io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: JcaPEMKeyConverter is provided by BouncyCastle, an optional dependency. To use support for EC Keys you must explicitly add this dependency to classpath.
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.CertUtils.handleECKey(CertUtils.java:164)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.CertUtils.loadKey(CertUtils.java:134)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.CertUtils.createKeyStore(CertUtils.java:112)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.CertUtils.createKeyStore(CertUtils.java:247)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.SSLUtils.keyManagers(SSLUtils.java:153)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.SSLUtils.keyManagers(SSLUtils.java:147)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.applyCommonConfiguration(HttpClientUtils.java:204)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(OkHttpClientFactory.java:89)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.SparkKubernetesClientFactory$.createKubernetesClient(SparkKubernetesClientFactory.scala:118)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.$anonfun$run$4(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:242)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2763)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:242)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:214)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:958)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1046)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1055)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
23/03/20 18:14:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/03/20 18:14:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/22/ntjwd5dx691gvkktkspl0f_00000gq/T/spark-15d1055d-c2fb-40d4-81ff-66b602595979
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stuck here for a while, I suddenly thought I met a same error  for Apache Flink last year at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68779353/2000548). So I tried similar approach and it worked for Apache Spark too!

Here is the solution:

Download latest version of `bcprov-jdk15on` and `bcpkix-jdk15on` jar files from

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on

In my case, I installed Apache Spark on macOS by `brew install apache-spark`, so my folder is at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark`, you need find your own location.

Then move those two jar files to this folder

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/{version}/libexec/jars/
```

Now I can submit the application again, and the error is gone!